# how to show/hide a pre tag on button click by setting a variable in pug template

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm using pug for the first time and am stuck on setting a local variable to display a div only once a button is clicked. this is what I tried:

```
extends layout

block content
  script.
    var something = function () {
      var display = true;
      console.log('hi', display);
    }
  button(href='#', type='button', onclick='something()') Get News Articles
  if display === true
    div.pre-space 
      pre
        code #{jsonArticles}
```

what am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the Javascript inside your script tag will only be run when the web page is rendered by the browser.

And all your Jade/Pug code is run on server side, which results in your html web page.

In your current situation, you can render the `div.pre-space` in Pug and keep it hidden using CSS. Then you can show it using Javascript on that button's click.

extends layout

```
block content
  script.
    var something = function () {
      document.querySelector("div.pre-space").style("display", "block");
    }
  button(href='#', type='button', onclick='something()') Get News Articles
  div.pre-space 
    pre
      code #{jsonArticles}
```

css:

```
div.pre-space{ display: none;}
```

Comment: querySelect is not a function `querySelector` should be there

Comment: thanks @ChanchalPrashantTapase for pointing that out. I have corrected it :)

Comment: this also not working...:) `style.display = 'block'`.. this is working for me

Comment: @ChanchalPrashantTapase Great you resolved your issue. I'll try to fix my solution if it's not working. Thanks :)